# Show that $\sum_{g \in G} \chi(g)=0$.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\chi$ be a non-trivial irreducible character of a finite group
$G$. Show that $$\sum_{g \in G} \chi(g)=0.$$ Here $\chi:G \to \Bbb C$ just a function such that $\chi_{\phi}(g)=Tr(\phi_g)$

I am not getting any clue. Please give some hint.

Comment: Notice that this property is a very general fact : if $G$
is a locally compact group (e.g. a finite group) and $m$ the right Haar measure on $G$, then any non-trivial character $\chi :G \to S^1 \subset \Bbb C^*$ satisfies $\displaystyle \int_G \chi dm = 0$.

Comment: $\sum_{g \in G} \chi(g)=\sum_{g \in G} \chi(g).1=\sum_{g \in G} \chi(g)\bar{\chi_e}(g)=|G|\langle \chi,\chi_e \rangle=0$. Note that $e$ is the trivial representation.

Answer (score 4):

Relate $\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g) $ to $\sum_{g\in G}\chi(ag)$ for suitable $a\in G$.

Comment: So that $\chi(a) \neq 1$ or $\chi(a)=0$. But why this kind of $\chi$ exists?

Comment: @use How do **you** define a character of a finite group? For me it is a homomorphism $\;G\to\Bbb C^*\;$ , so $\;\chi(a)=0\;$ is impossible. What solves your problem is thyat $\;\chi(a)\neq1\;$ as $\;\chi\;$ is a given as *non-trivial character*

Comment: Just a minute for me character is just a function from $G$ to $\Bbb C$ not $\Bbb C^*$ and for the standard representation of $S_3$ I know $\chi ((123))=0$

Comment: See my edited comment.

Comment: The answer should be for non-abelian groups $\chi(e)$ will solve my purpose and for linear character #Donantonio http://math.stackexchange.com/users/31254/donantonio is correct

Comment: See here I have a vital question that $\chi$ is not in general multiplicative. The definition used here is $\chi_{\phi}(g)=Tr(\phi_g)$

Comment: I think Swapnil's comment under my question is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

For any $a \in G$,
$\sum_{g \in G} \chi(G) = \sum_{g \in G} \chi(ag) = \chi(a) \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g)$

Since $\chi$ is a nontrivial character, there exists $a$ such that $\chi(a) \neq 1$.

Hence $\sum_{g \in G} \chi(G) = 0$.

Comment: See my comment in the previous answer.

Comment: What about $0$?